# Plotting multiple comets at the same time in SciLab

Tags: plot, scilab

The syntax for a single comet is `comet(<fx>,<fy>,...)` where `fx` and `fy` are the "abscissa" - a word I had to look up - and the "ordinate" - which I also had to look up - of the comet's position, respectively. The documentation provides that if `fx` and `fy` are matrices, then each column gives the coordinates for a separate comet, along with an example using `comet(<fx>,[<f1y>,<f2y>,...],...)`.

I tried this with `comet([<f1x>,<f2x>,...],[<f1y>,<f2y>,...],...)` thinking that it would plot each pair separately, but the result was the same as if I had created column vectors `fx` and `fy` by joining `f1x,f2x,...` and `f1y,f2y,...`, respectively, and used `comet(fx,fy)`.

How do I show two or more comets with different abscissae *at the same time* (preferably without building some kind of `multicomet` function from the ground up)?

Comment: There is not 50-50 chance that any given Scilab function and its Matlab functional equivalent share lower-level guts. I would dare say (and I hope so because of copyright issues) that it tends to zero. The function calls might be almost identical for such a pair of functions, but the way they are implemented is probably different, *especially* for curve-plotting. There are way more approaches to curve-plotting than there are to, say, calculating Discrete Fourier Transform.

Comment: Also, which verison of Scilab and which OS are you using? With Scilab 6.1.1 on Windows 10 I can plot two independent comets with the function call you suggested, like this: `ts=0:0.1:2*%pi; comet([cos(ts'), 0.5*cos(ts')], [sin(ts'), 0.5*sin(ts')]);` Indeed, it is undocumented behavior, but somehow it works for me.

Comment: @luispauloml: it IS documented : it is the body of the second example. And for 2 input matrices, the description says `If x and y are matrices with identical sizes, then animated curves are drawn for each pair (x(:,j),y(:,j)).`  : https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/comet.html

Comment: @S.Gougeon I see it now, it is documented. I guess I was biased by the question, read the help page too fast and ended up skipping that part. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

if fx1,fx2,... and fy1,fy2, ... are column vectors with same size

```
    comet([fx1 fx2 ...], [fy1, fy2,..])  will do the job
```